# Facebook API, comments not showing

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots

I'm making a page, with the concept that If someone reply's on a specific post, my page reply's automatic on them. So, I've made a Python-program and let it run 24/7. For me as page-administrator, app-administrator (Facebook app), it works perfect. But, when I react with an other account (normal user, no admin), then I my program returns TraceError 'from'. So, then the program can't find who has reacted...

I've got a small second question. When I go to the page with the other account, I can see the reactions my admin-account placed, but I can't see the auto-reactions my program wrote. So, with my admin account, I see a reaction, with my other account, I just see "show 1 reaction", but when I click on it, it disappears...

Someone who has an idea how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a working minimum example, so that we can look at your code to figure out whats wrong. Also this is a good resource to consult before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is your app live, not in dev mode still? Did you get whatever permissions and features it uses reviewed by Facebook already?